# How can I assign properties to a custom UIControl using Xcode 4 and iOS 4.3 outside of code?

Tags: ios, xcode4, ios4, interface-builder, uicontrol

I've got a custom button class which subclasses `UIControl`, and I can successfully add instances of it into my XIBs using Xcode 4. I can also use "User Defined Runtime Attributes" in the Identity Inspector to give the buttons titles and font sizes, etc.

However, this seems to only be supported in iOS 5.0 and later, and I would like to support iOS 4.3. Is there some other way to either assign custom properties to these objects in the GUI? Obviously I can put them in my code, but that is undesirable for hopefully obvious reasons.

Failing that, is there some best practice for maintaining view properties like this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, user defined properties in the nib file are not supported prior to iOS 5.0. A good way to check what kind of nib support you have is to change the nib's target deployment to your desired target deployment. In this instance, you'll get an error right away if you change the nib target deployment to 4.3 that these properties aren't supported in iOS 4.

Unfortunately, you'll have to do this in code or use something like a property file if you're targeting 4.x.